# Import multiple images into attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, image

Does anyone know how to tie multiple images to attributes within a shapefile attribute table at once?

I am working with a point shapefile within a geodatabase that has a total of 2500 rows of data that need two image attachments each. Each row has a unique ID that corresponds with the image (Labeled by ID) that needs to be tied to it. I am working within ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: Are you after an attribute join http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000064000000? There is also Join Field http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/ that will add the table to every matching row. Both require a unique matching field exists between shapefile and table. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I would be interested in joining the images but they are not currently in a table format. All of my images are currently stored within a folder outside of my geodatabase as JPEGs. 

I was able to create a match table using the images however get an "ERROR 001179: Attachments are not enabled for this dataset" warning when trying to run the "Add Attachments" tool.

When trying to enable my attachments, it has been giving me a notice that my attachments are already enabled.

I've never worked with this sort of data or these extensions and may be missing a step?

Comment: Are you trying to create a hyperlink to existing images or appending classified values from a georeferenced raster? From the sound of it you're trying to embed the images into the features which is not an easy operation, my comment was expecting a classified raster with an attribute table. Shapefiles cannot contain a raster field but you can create a hyperlink. See http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/adding-raster-datasets-as-attributes-in-a-feature-class.htm

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to actually embed the images into my feature class. Thank you for your responses though!

Comment: Shapefiles don't support raster fields, you would need to import into a file geodatabase and add a raster field (or two) to embed the images. I haven't done this myself but I believe it's possible via python if there's a way to match up pictures with features. Have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t000001np000000 about putting pictures into features.

Answer (score 1):

Try the batch version of the Add Attachments tool by right clicking it > Batch (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-attachments.htm). Pay attention to the in_match_table, since thaty dictates where and how the tool joins the attachments.